# What is the actual purpose of mathematica.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

It seems to me that I have misunderstood mathematica.stackexchange.com's purposes. I understood two purposes: to teach and to learn. It seems to be a place for ignorant newcomers to Mathematica to demonstrate their limited knowledge of Mathematica and their limited programming experience and for the mandarins to receive kowtows from such people on the basis of snide comments which if you already had most of answer *might* be just enough to bring the original questioner to enlightenment. If the issue is handled at all, then it usually is answered finally someone just a little more advanced than the original questioner whose has determined an answer.

[Can/should we have additional reasons for closing?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/661/can-should-we-have-additional-reasons-for-closing) alludes to some of these issues:

1. ..., the asker may be an absolute beginner who simply does not know where to begin or hasn't yet arrived at a coherent conceptual model of how Mathematica works.
2. Moreover, they are the kind of questions to which anyone with <s>any</s> *considerable* familiarity with Mathematica already knows the answer without even having to think about it, but where a new user may need a push in the right direction. *A push in the correct direction is *not* a bare **RTFM**. It is providing instruction on which Fine Manual (page) to Read; if necessary, how to access that manual; and, possibly which line to read.*
3. *The practice given hints in comments is frustrating.* Please, see [How do you define the domain of a plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2250/how-do-you-define-the-domain-of-a-plot) “@mike The answer in your comment is correct, but in the future you'd better provide it as a formal answer in the answer box and preferably with a bit of explanation. – Sjoerd C. de Vries Feb 24, 2012 at 13:00”

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic -- In particular, "... some proof of minimal Mathematica knowledge...."

Comment: @user:4999 What is basis of your determination that I lack minimal Mathematica knowledge?

Comment: I don't remember saying that. What makes you think that is what I determined?

Comment: The hostile tone of this post and increasingly often of this user is not acceptable and should be challenged. I'm flagging this to the moderators.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it sounds like a self-indulgent rant rather than a sincere invitation to discuss a constructive topic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP left the site and didn't seem to care to receive honest answers from community members.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm sorry this ended up being the outcome of this. I hope I wasn't too hard on my response. I do believe in everything I said, but may be I could have expressed is differently.

Comment: @rhermans I don't have any idea. I hadn't really noticed the user until the reply to my comment. I hadn't had any interaction with them until my comment. I was surprised they took it as an attack on them. Made me think I had somehow offended them earlier. The attitude in the two meta posts are consistent with them being on the brink of losing patience with the site. I thought you treated them with respect. They apparently were not in a frame of mind to accept being (deservedly) criticized and challenged, though. Perhaps the mods challenged them, too. I can't see it as your fault.

Answer (score 7):

*However undeserving, I will humor the question on the title first and later address the inappropriate rant in the question body.*

## Answer

The primary purpose of stackexchange.com is to be an **Expert Community** that shares knowledge and earns trust by working on the process of **curating high-quality questions and answers**.[1]

In particular, *Mathematica Stack Exchange* is for users of the software *Mathematica* developed by *Wolfram Research*, as well as related products like *Wolfram Engine*, *gridMathematica*, *Wolfram Workbench*, and the *CDF Player*. [2]

It is a community-driven space, so **people** have developed a culture that welcomes new users to ask and answer questions about *Wolfram Mathematica*. This **expert community culture** also expects all members to show some minimum effort and diligence designed to ensure the content ends up being a valuable resource for both novice and experienced users. The community is committed to providing high-quality **curated information**.

The **curation process** implies weeding out bad-quality questions and answers, so people can easily find the high-quality content. Posts that fail to articulate a good question or answer as a consequence of **insufficient diligence are not good content**. The site's guidelines also discourages verbose or subjective posts, rants, duplicates, and chatty or tolling comments for the same reason.

Instead, users are expected to be respectful and helpful, and they are encouraged to provide constructive feedback. Questions should be clear, concise, and well-researched. Answers should be comprehensive, accurate, and helpful. That's hard to achieve but necessary. That's why questions and answers are continuously edited and commented to improve and update them. This helps to create a positive and productive learning environment for everyone, including both experienced and new users.

## About the rant

It's clear to me that this question was not an straightforward call for discussion but a rant to vent some frustration. In this form, this question is not suitable for this site and the OP should reflect on their attitude.

The **trolling remarks** of the OP are clearly violating the code of conduct [3] that defines subtle put-downs or unfriendly language as *Unacceptable Behavior*. *Mathematica Stack Exchange* is **NOT** a place for inexperienced newcomers to demonstrate their limited familiarity.  It is **NOT** a place for senior members to mock people in need of help. It is **NOT** a place to exchange for excessively subservient remarks. The OP maliciously suggests the opposite with the **intention to provoke**.

In my personal opinion, the sarcastic tone of the OP is hostile and does not benefit this site. This question is not constructive or helpful, but apparently intended to upset others. This kind of content should be challenged. I hope the OP learns from this critique and the moderators can react promptly to remove such content.

## References

[1] https://stackexchange.com/

[2] https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

[3] https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/conduct

Comment: @user:10397 Thank you for making my argument for me!  “*Mathematica Stack Exchange* is **NOT** a place for inexperienced newcomers to demonstrate their limited familiarity.”

Comment: I used the word *mandarin* in this meaning: “A member of an elite group, especially a person having influence or high status in intellectual or cultural circles.” (The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 5th Edition.) I regret that that meaning was misunderstood.

Comment: @IAmANaïf we understand very well what you mean, but I will not replicate your mocking choice of words. Nobody is making an argument for you. Your question is among the 8 lowest scores ever, there is clearly a consensus that it's you who is off the mark here.

Comment: “[*Mathematica Stack Exchange*] is **NOT** a place for senior members to mock people in need of help.” Then, I ask: where are the tutorials and lists of (F)requently(A)sked(Q)uestions that can be linked to and referred to when someone does ask a question that the *senior members* deem to be a poor quality question and mock that question without giving a more detailed, appropriate response. I opine that there are no poor questions, only poor answers.

Comment: There are none, it's an *"Expert Community"*  not a *"First steps programming tutorial"* site. That said, inexperienced people are welcome, people don't need to *know* to participate, but they need to show due diligence. Questions should be clear, concise, and **well-researched**. There are many resources, here and elsewhere. Some Q&A may get close to what you ask, like [18393](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/10397), but if you want tutorials, that shows a misunderstanding of what this site is.

Comment: There are bad questions, yours is one. A rant with insults, zero research, no attempts to show any efforts, no respect for the culture in the community. Stating that is not to mock the user. Your opinion is that "there are no poor questions", here the community agrees otherwise.